# Does this sentence "He's too thin to carry it" make any sense to you?

Tags: expressions

Does this sentence "He's too thin to carry it" make any sense to you?
This is really bothering me for quite a long time!

Comment: What context did you hear it in? - I don't think I have ever heard it used before (Australia).

Comment: The answer to this question seems already implicit in the answer to [Is saying “he's too thin to carry it (some very heavy stuff)” a euphemism?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30434/is-saying-hes-too-thin-to-carry-it-some-very-heavy-stuff-a-euphemism)

Comment: Please provide context.

Answer (score 1):

You could aid us in providing any peripheral context.

Stabbing at it as is, though, I would take it to mean that:

> *he is of too small a stature and / or too feeble to lift and transport what is at hand.*

That is not to say that the person is generally small or feeble, that would be far too presumptuous; only that this stands relatively to what it is that requires carrying.

Comment: Thin has a meaning of "not well fleshed," but does it also carry a meaning of "being weak or feeble"? In the Merriam-Webster, it does carry a meaning of "lacking substance of strength," but it uses "thin plot/broth" to make the example.
Is it okay to say someone is to thin to do anything which needs a lot of strength? I just find it misleading to say, because thin doesn't always means weak. If you google, there is a title such as "Michael Jackson is too thin to play live." Is it OK to say so? Somebody argued that it's a euphemism to say so.

Comment: thin never necessary means to be weak or lack of strengh, actually, this is an issue over which we had a violent quarrel. And I think it's never a way for native-speaker to say that and the opposition argued: 1.it's a euphemism; 2.it says there in the Merriam-Webster dic, but again, I think it only referrs to things not humans; 3.the googled and enumerated this many links to say "thin" also carries a meaning of "being weak", since none of us is native-speaker, I thought maybe, it's better to ask here, thank you for your help, the below are the links they gathered from google

Comment: http://www.stuff.co.nz/entertainment/music/2392869/Jacko-too-thin-to-perform-live

Comment: gamespot.com/forums/topic/26455752 too thin to play inside setonhall.rivals.com/… too thin to play the 4 gamefaqs.com/boards/921183-fire-emblem-the-sacred-stones/… too thin to wield a hatchet. forum.narniaweb.com/viewtopic.php?p=166386 Both of these things caused his surgery to be postponed as he's too thin to make it through.

Comment: @Daisy: Thin does not always mean weak, no. Thin is even an attractive quality to some people - not because they are associating it with weakness - and so to come across as if this is a derogatory term would be fallacious. When used here, in the given context, you qualify what is meant by thin for the current scenario.

Comment: @Daisy: Each of your examples use the construct of _'too thin'_, this immediately tries to indicate an inferiority in circumstance, of sorts. If you think about how one might apply this as complementary then remove the _'too x to do'_ construct, such as: '_He's just thin enough to get into his wedding suit'_, or _'She's nice and thin'_.